# AngularJS / CSS - show/hide element on mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

This code only applies the `.current` class to my span, but the span is not hidden in the first place. I want it to be hidden, then on `hover + ctrl` - displayed, and on `mouseleave` - hidden again. How can I achieve that?

html:

```
<div class="portlet-titlebar" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()">    
    <span class="remove" class="hidden">
          <clr-icon shape="times-circle" class="is-warning" size="16"></clr-icon>
    </span>
</div>
```

directive:

```
scope.hoverIn = function(){
    var res = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
    var result = angular.element(res);
    if(event.ctrlKey){
      result.removeClass('hidden');
      result.addClass('current');
   }
}
```

less:

```
  .hidden{
    display:none;
  }

  .current{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

Comment: I suggest you to make it just with css - i.e `.remove:hover {...}`

Comment: I would, but it has to be shown on hover + ctrl key pressed, not just on hover..

Comment: @Vluis If its already hidden how will you hover over it?

Comment: I'm hovering over it's parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question, this is my solution, on hovering the `ng-mouseover($event)` will track the hovering, then a if condition will check if `ctrl` key is pressed, you need to pass the `$event` through the function. Then on mouse leave you need the `ng-mouseleave` directive to detect this and call another function to hide it again.

Now coming to your question, if you want the span to be intially hidden then just add the class `hidden` to the `span` initially.

I have added the below CSS class so that the container does not become very small, to facilitate easy hovering.

```
.portlet-titlebar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

Here is a working demo, let me know if there are any issues, we can sort it out.

---

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: Awsome, thanks alot, but only thing is that I can't access the element with element[0].parentNode as the code I posted is just a snippet, I have other elements above, so it's not working. I tried :

angular.element(element.getElementsByClassName("remove hidden")).removeClass('hidden');

but i get 

An error occurred in the client
s.getElementsByClassName is not a function

Comment: I changed it to:  

var result = document.getElementsByClassName("remove hidden");  
var wrappedResult = angular.element(result);  

But for some reason the hoverOut is not working, any idea why that would be?  

scope.hoverOut = function() {  
                 var result = document.getElementsByClassName("remove hidden");  
                 var wrappedResult = angular.element(result);  
                 wrappedResult.removeClass('current');  
                 wrappedResult.addClass('hidden');  
             }

Comment: @Vluis can you check my updated answer? the problem is angular does not have a good way to find a specific parent element, so I take the element we get from the event, which is `portlet-titlebar` and find the span instead, we can use the `.find()` method to find the `span`

Comment: @Vluis Does this help you?

Comment: @Vluis Great! Glad to help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155743/discussion-between-vluis-and-naren-murali).